# Local Notification not called

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to implement localNotification.It do not reload my table. Please Help thanks in advance.I add item and then on saving item. it not reload table it became blank.My Debugger is not reach reload data function.

In My ViewController1.m

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *date=[datepicker date];
    NSString *taskString =task.text;
    UILocalNotification *localnotification=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    localnotification.fireDate=date;
    localnotification.alertBody=taskString;
    localnotification.alertAction=@"Show Me The Item";
    localnotification.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localnotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localnotification];



   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadTable)
                                                 name:@"reloadData"
                                               object:nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)add:(id)sender
{
    ViewController1 *sec=[[ViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:sec animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication ]scheduledLocalNotifications]count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"ViewController";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Get list of local notifications
    NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Display notification info
    [cell.textLabel setText:localNotification.alertBody];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[localNotification.fireDate description]];

    return cell;


}
-(void)reloadTable
{
    [table reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Why here you are using notification. In my understanding without notification you can reload the table. Call directly the reloadTable function

Comment: my table is on another controller.

Comment: @rohanthankur: Are you un-registering from notification from anywhere in that view controller ?

Comment: sir ji my table count is 0. it not save local notification

Comment: in your save button you are sending 'self' object in local post notification.Why? try it with nil like this.[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSNotificationCenter` for this. It works like a radio antenna. First, you should register to this station in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTable:) name:@"reloadData" object:nil];
```

And then on your different ViewController send this radio signal which will be received by all classes, that listens to this station. Send message like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:nil];
```

Now your ViewController will reload data on demand.

Comment: Does your `-(void)reloadTable` gets even called? Log something in it. Is your other ViewController (the one on which you want to reload data) initialized? That should definitely work, I used this numerous times...